# calculating a posterior mean + median + 95% probability int

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, posterior

This question comes from the *Bayesian Thinking in Biostatistics* textbook.

So I've been given a dataset where the mean is shown to be 134.5 and the variance 242.2.

Using a normal prior for the population mean μ ~ N(130, 100), I need to plot the posterior and prior distributions of μ and obtain the posterior mean and median as well as a 95% posterior probability interval for μ.

My intuition and findings show that I think I need to use the conjugate prior somehow here. I know that the posterior is the (likelihood*prior)/avg likelihood

I don't really know what to do after this here.

EDIT: I think I might be on to something here...

```
posterior_mean <- ((((404*134.5)/242.2)+(130/100))/((404/242.2)+(1/100)))

posterior_variance <- 1/((404/242.2)+(1/100))
```

Where 404 is the number of observations. Thus producing an answer of the posterior mean = 134.5 and posterior variance = 0.61.

My next question is why is the posterior variance so small compared to the prior variance?

Comment: "why is the posterior variance so small compared to the prior variance" ... because of the way the sample size impacts the likelihood, meaning that typically, large samples lead to tight posteriors. Here the product of individual-observation likelihoods (because of independence) yields a sum in the exponent. An $n$-term comes out when you collect terms with the same power in $\mu$ and complete the square in $\mu$ that's in the exponent. Combining with the prior leads to a harmonic mean of prior and likelihood-terms; that variance is dominated by the smaller term, that from the likelihood.

Comment: ... The contribution from the likelihood works in a very similar way that in a frequentist calculation of the variance of a sample mean, you have that it is proportional to $\frac{1}{n}$.